# Is this the simplest form for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am trying to simplify $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x}$$

Would I be able to move the $\sqrt{x}$ under the other radical so it would become $$\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{x})x}$$
$$\sqrt{(x+x\sqrt{x})}$$

I vaguely remember a rule which allowed me to do this but I wasn't really sure. I have checked this on WolframAlpha and the $\sqrt{x}$ was not moved into the other radical. Could someone clarify whether or not this works? Thank you!

Comment: $\rm (ab)^c=a^cb^c$ has as corollary $\rm \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$* via setting $\rm c=1/2$, here with $\rm a=1+\sqrt{x}$ and $\rm b=x$. (*This works when not both of $\rm a,b$ are negative. This rule does not generally work otherwise, due to branch issues in the complex plane.)

Comment: There is no single notion of "simplest." Certainly your "simplification" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Wolframalpha didn't find any other alternates, so I would guess you cannot simplify it anymore: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%2Bxsqrt%28x%29%29